# how to call result out side the pool.query in node js

Tags: node.js, node-modules, monodevelop

i am create node js API , getting one problem please let me know solution , 
here is my code

```
 var searchdataArray = [];  
 SearchData.forEach(function(item){
    SearchDataJson.KeyTags = item.hashtags;
    // var d =  await globalVar.data.trendingPodData();
    // console.log(d);
    var sql = "SELECT email , mobile from user_profile where id=228 limit 2";
   pool.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
     var myJSON = JSON.stringify(result);
     var array = JSON.parse(myJSON); 
     SearchDataJson.Data = array;
     searchdataArray.push(SearchDataJson);
     console.log(searchdataArray);
    });  
});
```

my requirement is getting searchdataArray variable out side the poo.query function.

Comment: Please help me , i am new in node js

Comment: It is outside the function has just not finished yet.  you need a promise or await to be sure it is done.

Comment: Can you let me know how to resolved that usign promise and await

Comment: var searchdataArray = [];  
     SearchData.forEach( async function(item){
         SearchDataJson.KeyTags = item.hashtags;
         searchdataArray=  await globalVar.data.trendingPodData(); }): i have tried this one as well but searchdataArray this array is not used out side the function

Comment: you need the await outside the loop

Comment: Can you give me example for that